# WGCNA package: value matching function output contains wrong NAs

Tags: r, match, network-analysis

I use WGCNA package for analyzing the co-expressed genes. Here I try to Form a data frame analogous to expression data that will hold the clinical traits. and i use the following codes:

table for traitData

| x  | sample    | NoduleperPlant    |

|-   |-  |-  |

| 1  | 1021_verbena_rep_1    | 2     |

| 2  | 1021_verbena_rep_2    | 3     |

| 3  | 1021_verbena_rep_3    | 1     |

| 4  | 1021_camporegio_rep_1     | 2     |

| 5  | 1021_camporegio_rep_2     | 3     |

| 6  | 1021_camporegio_rep_3     | 4     |

| 7  | BL225C_camporegio_rep_1   | 5     |

| 8  | BL225C_camporegio_rep_2   | 4     |

| 9  | BL225C_camporegio_rep_3   | 1     |

Table  dfxpr (some of the genes are presented in table)

|FIELD1                 |aacC-1|aacC4-1|aapJ-1|aapM-1|aapP-1|aapQ-1|aarF-1|

|-----------------------|------|-------|------|------|------|------|------|

|X1021_verbena_rep_1    |42    |46     |12412 |935   |3354  |2876  |550   |

|X1021_verbena_rep_2    |52    |37     |11775 |946   |2970  |2824  |514   |

|X1021_verbena_rep_3    |12    |22     |5077  |397   |1462  |1228  |230   |

|X1021_camporegio_rep_1 |52    |71     |12983 |1454  |3408  |3248  |707   |

|X1021_camporegio_rep_2 |20    |65     |9240  |803   |2807  |3146  |445   |

|X1021_camporegio_rep_3 |28    |53     |11030 |1065  |3480  |3410  |582   |

|BL225C_camporegio_rep_1|29    |19     |6346  |375   |938   |768   |118   |

|BL225C_camporegio_rep_2|51    |62     |12938 |781   |1765  |1629  |291   |

|BL225C_camporegio_rep_3|52    |43     |6462  |504   |1120  |1091  |238   |

```
traitData = read.csv("NodulPerPlantTraitForLowGroup.csv"); #this csv file contains 3 columns as the first column is non-relevant information, second column contains the names of samples and the third column holds the values measured for the traits. 
    # remove columns that hold information I do not need.
    allTraits = traitData[, -1];
    allTraits = allTraits[, 1:2];
    # Form a data frame analogous to expression data that will hold the clinical traits.
    lowNoduleSamples = rownames(dfxpr) #dfxpr is a data frame containing 9 observations (i.e. samples) and 6398 variables (i.e. genes)
    traitRows = match(lowNoduleSamples, allTraits$sample); #here is the line i get wrong values as NAs while i know they all should match
    datTraits = allTraits[traitRows, -1]; #then this lines result NAs too
    rownames(datTraits) = allTraits[traitRows, 1];
    collectGarbage();
```

how can I fix the problem?

Comment: Hi, it is impossible to help you if we don't have a minimal reproducible example of your dataset. I encourage you to edit your post with the output of `dput(head(traitData))` so that people could reproduce your issue. thanks

Comment: Hi there, this is the structure of trait Data

structure(list(X = 1:6, sample = c("1021_verbena_rep_1", "1021_verbena_rep_2", 
"1021_verbena_rep_3", "1021_camporegio_rep_1", "1021_camporegio_rep_2", 
"1021_camporegio_rep_3"), NodulePerPlant = c(2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
4L, 2L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: We will also need an example of `dfxpr`, the 10 first genes for instance

Comment: i added example dfxpr data frame in the question

Comment: Unfortunately this is not readable for us in this format, we would just need the output of `dput(head(dfxpr))` same as you perfectly gave us in the comment for traitData

Comment: <p> Here is an abstract of <mark>dfxpr </mark> data frame. Due to comment character limitations a just one gene is added.
<p> ,... , `zwf-1` = c(738, 
    628, 336, 789, 538, 801)), row.names = c("X1021_verbena_rep_1", 
"X1021_verbena_rep_2", "X1021_verbena_rep_3", "X1021_camporegio_rep_1", 
"X1021_camporegio_rep_2", "X1021_camporegio_rep_3"), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 0):

I have Added a "drop = FALSE" to this line: datTraits = allTraits[traitRows, -1]

datTraits = allTraits[traitRows, -1, drop = FALSE]

I realized that my allTraits contains only 2 columns; when  I remove the first one, I'm left with just one column and R converts that into a single vector unless I add the drop = FALSE argument.